# Store TreeView nodes for filtering

Tags: c#, treeview

I've done this before with a `DataGridView`, but is there some way to mask the visible `TreeView` nodes so that on a TextChanged event I can hide/filter nodes that do not contain the `TextBox` text? I have a lot of nodes.

Currently, this works, but it's a "remove only" function, doesn't add the nodes back if I delete some text from the `textBox`. Thanks in advance.

```
//Change in text will hide non matching nodes (remove only)
for (int i = 0; i<dirTree.Nodes.Count; i++)
{
    if(!dirTree.Nodes[i].Text.Contains(custNameTB.Text))
    {
       dirTree.Nodes.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe keep a 'Master' node with all the nodes as children in memory. If there is no search text then just add that to the treeview. Then, if there is search text typed in, go thru the 'master' node and use it to create another filtered node (with the desired nodes as children) and add it to the treeview.

Basically you are just creating 2 collections on nodes. I with all the nodes (permanent) and another that just has copies of the desired node (transitory).

Answer (score 0):

you could not make your node not visible (you have to add/remove it)
why
because how make a node visible and his child node visible it will be hard ( imagine ten nested node with 5 not ok..)
another solution is to store you treeview ( in a treeview you set not visible or in a datatable but more complicated) and have a treeview to display so if you remove node it is only on the duplicate treeview (the not visible treeview will stay and you will not lose nodes)